# d3 scrollable timeline from min to max value

Tags: d3.js

There is a timeline http://jsfiddle.net/uWdkw/
The code I wrote is given below. I want to add a min and max date value and scroll only from min date value to max date value. How can I implement this? Can someone please help me with this.

```
 var w = 500,
h = 300,
x = d3.time.scale().range([0, w]),  
xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickSize(-h, 0).tickPadding(6); 

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h+50)
.append("svg:g");

svg.append("svg:g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")");

svg.append("svg:rect")
.attr("class", "pane")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h)
.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", zoom));

x.domain([new Date(1999, 0, 1), new Date(2014, 0, 0)]);

draw();

function draw() {
  console.log ("drawing");
  svg.select("g.x.axis").call(xAxis);
}

function zoom() {
  console.log("zooming");
  d3.event.transform(x); // TODO d3.behavior.zoom should support extents
  draw();
}
```

Comment: Cannot help but do you really need this with D3? I used TimeGlider in my project which was fine so far (http://arda-maps.org/ages/first/ the TIMELINE button). Maybe you need it also in this way.